# Issue with drive management when trying to access phone's memory

Tags: windows, phone

When I plug in my phone, it gets recognised only after a couple of minutes and when it does I can't access it. Ubuntu thinks it's a camera and not just any drive.

The box that pops up says:

"**Unable to access Lumia 630 (RM 976)**

Error initialising camera: -53: Could not claim USB device."

Any solutions?

PC is running Ubuntu 15.04

Phone is running W10 Developer preview, penultimate build. [bad idea]